# Yii2 PHPWord addListItem not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, yii2, phpword

I am using PhpWord extension in Yii2.
Having a problem, when using addListItem. Is it not working. Printing empty this block. Other printing good.

My code:

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

// Define styles
    $fontStyleName = 'myOwnStyle';
    $phpWord->addFontStyle($fontStyleName, array('color' => 'FF0000'));

    $paragraphStyleName = 'P-Style';
    $phpWord->addParagraphStyle($paragraphStyleName, array('spaceAfter' => 95));

    $multilevelNumberingStyleName = 'multilevel';
    $phpWord->addNumberingStyle(
        $multilevelNumberingStyleName,
        array(
            'type'   => 'multilevel',
            'levels' => array(
                array('format' => 'decimal', 'text' => '%1.', 'left' => 360, 'hanging' => 360, 'tabPos' => 360),
                array('format' => 'upperLetter', 'text' => '%2.', 'left' => 720, 'hanging' => 360, 'tabPos' => 720),
            ),
        )
    );

    $predefinedMultilevelStyle = array('listType' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\ListItem::TYPE_NUMBER_NESTED);

// New section
        $section = $phpWord->addSection();

// Lists
        $section->addText('Multilevel list.');
        $section->addListItem('List Item I', 0, null, $multilevelNumberingStyleName);
        $section->addListItem('List Item I.a', 1, null, $multilevelNumberingStyleName);
        $section->addListItem('List Item I.b', 1, null, $multilevelNumberingStyleName);
        $section->addListItem('List Item II', 0, null, $multilevelNumberingStyleName);
        $section->addListItem('List Item II.a', 1, null, $multilevelNumberingStyleName);
        $section->addListItem('List Item III', 0, null, $multilevelNumberingStyleName);
        $section->addTextBreak(2);

// saving
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="first.docx"');
        header('Content-Type: application/msword');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
      

        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'ODText');
        $objWriter->save("php://output");
```

Help please. I will be very grateful for your help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Everything turned out to be very simple and more beautiful.
For output need use standart function Yii, and before downloading save file in system.

```
$objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord);
$objWriter->save('uploads/doc.docx');

Yii::$app->response->sendFile('uploads/doc.docx');
```